# Ruby permutation method code without using Enumerable classes or hash or map

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a very naive "string permutations" method in Ruby. I want to try without using any Enumerable class (or hash or map) methods of `Array` class. I pasted the snippet of my code below for reference. This method is listing all the string permutations but it is returning a `Range` at the end (as shown in the output it is printing `0..2` at the end). I am not able to find out the reason for this and need some guidance on this. Thank you.

```
def permute(str, left, right) 
  if (left == right) 
    puts str
    return str 
  else
    for i in left..right
      str = swap(str,left,i)
      permute(str, left+1, right)
      str = swap(str,left,i)
    end
  end
end

def swap(s, l, r)
  ch_arr = s.split""

  tmp = ch_arr[r]
  ch_arr[r] = ch_arr[l]
  ch_arr[l] = tmp

  ch_arr.join
end

puts permute("abc", 0, 2)

Output: 

abc
acb
bac
bca
cba
cab
0..2
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of a Ruby method is always the result of the last statement evaluated. In your `permute` method, the `else` case is implicitly returning the result of the `for` loop. The result of a `for` loop that terminates normally will return the original range, so you are getting `left..right` range for the 'top' call in the recursion. You just want to ensure that you return `str` in that case:

```rb
else
  for i in left..right
    str = swap(str,left,i)
    permute(str, left+1, right)
    str = swap(str,left,i)
  end
  str
end
```

Output:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cba
cab
abc
```

As an aside, in the case where you use `break` to terminate a loop early, the implicit result is `nil` if `break` is used by itself, or is the value given to `break`.

```rb
for i in left..right
  break
end
=> nil

for i in left..right
  break :foo
end
=> :foo
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking time to help me understand the issue with my code. Also thanks for providing the details about `break`. I fixed my code and it is working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the last expression evaluated inside a method / block / module / class body is the value for the whole thing.

In the `permute` method, the last expression evaluated inside the method body is the `if` conditional expression, so the value of the `if` conditional expression will become the return value of the *whole* method.

The value of an `if` conditional expression is the value of the branch that was taken, i.e. if the `then` is taken, the value of the `then` branch becomes the value of the whole `if` conditional expression, and if the `else` branch is taken, the value of the `else` branch becomes the value of the whole `if` conditional expression.

The value of the `then` branch in your case, well, it doesn't really have a value, because you `return` out of it, so it never gets a chance to complete. But note that the `return` is actually useless here: if the `return` keyword were not there, the return value of the method would be the value of the `if` conditional expression, which would be the value of the `then` branch, which would be the value of the last expression evaluated inside the branch, which would be `str`. In other words, if you leave out the `return`, your code does exactly the same thing but would be much more idiomatic Ruby.

Now, the interesting case relevant to your question is the `else` branch. The last expression evaluated inside your `else` branch is the `for` / `in` expression. `for` / `in` is mostly syntactic sugar for `#each` (modulo the fact that it doesn't create a new scope as a normal block would, but that is not relevant here). `#each` (more specifically in this case `Range#each` although it doesn't really matter because all `#each` methods behave the same) always returns its receiver.

So, let's recap: the return value of `permute` is the value of the last expression evaluated inside its body, which is the `if` conditional expression. The value of the `if` conditional expression is the value of the branch that was taken. (In this example, the interesting case is the `else` branch.) The value of the `else` branch is the value of the last expression evaluated inside the branch, which is the `for` / `in` expression. The value of the `for` / `in` expression is the return value of the `#each` method that it desugars into. The return value of *any* `#each` method, by convention, is its receiver. And in your case, the `for` / `in` expression desugars into:

```rb
(left..right).each do |i|
  str = swap(str,left,i)
  permute(str, left+1, right)
  str = swap(str,left,i)
end
```

So, the return value of the `Range#each` method is `left..right`, which then becomes the value of the `for` / `in` expression, which then becomes the value of the `else` branch, which then becomes the value of the `if` conditional expression, which then becomes the return value of the whole `permute` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the details. Very well explained!! I fixed my code and it is working as expected.